# Securing CloudFront video on a SaaS platform

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, video-hosting

I have few videos which needs to be embedded in a SaaS LMS platform. Is there a possibility of making it available only if played from the SaaS platform.

I looked at the Origin Access Identity - they all operate on IP based restrictions - same thing with WAF as well.

Essentially the content needs to be available only inside the LMS; if in case we use the URL outside i.e. directly in the browser - an error or forbidden to be delivered.

Any approaches if this can be done ?

Comment: Would cloudfront signed URLs with a very short timeout work for this? They would not prevent people from being able to watch in another browser tab, but they would prevent people from being able to copy the link to the video and send it to someone else for viewing, which is what I'm guessing your end goal is.

Comment: Thanks for the response EEAA - it would to certain extend but that adds the overhead of changing the URLs in SaaS LMS frequently plus the issue of not making it available out of the LMS doesn't get addressed fully

Comment: Your LMS would just generate URLs dynamically on page load.

Comment: EEAA - i didn't think about that approach - let me check the LMS. Is there any other alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Use CloudFront and signed URLs if you can change the URLS easily. If you can't you can consider using [signed cookies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html), but again it might need application changes.

There's plenty of information about it in the [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html).